# ImageView shows rotated bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a ImageView in my activity that should show picture taken by camera But it shows rotated image Like picture!

Code to open camera:

```
i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(photoFile != null){
                i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
            }
```

creatImageFile method:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File picDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File storageDir = new File(picDir, "Amir Sasani");
    if(!storageDir.exists()){
        storageDir.mkdir();
    }
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

set bitmap to ImageView:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

ScreenShot of app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lki0N.png

What should I do to show picture correctly

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
imgView.setRotation(90);
```