# Bitmap compression poor quality

Tags: java, android, bitmap, compression

The following code completely destroys the quality of the image I am capturing with my android camera. How can I compress slightly without ruining the image quality

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
byte[] dataBAOS = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: It's not the compression. You're saving a thumbnail, which is what is returned on the data `Intent` for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. If you want the full-size image, you'll need to pass an `EXTRA_OUTPUT` extra on the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent` to tell the camera app where to store it, since it'll be too big to pass back on an `Intent`. Have a look at CommonsWare's examples on the linked duplicates.

Comment: @MikeM Thank you so much! Where can I find that example?

Comment: There are links in a banner at the top of your question now. You might need to refresh the page. Here they are again, just in case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45388784/picture-taken-with-camera-intent-is-low-quality-on-imageview-7-0, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352420/bitmap-bad-quality-after-set-to-imageview.